# Suds response time measurement

Tags: python, suds

Is there a way to make suds (python) returning the last call response time?

A kind of:

```
result = self.EchoPort.service['echoPort']['echo'](request="ping")
time= self.EchoPort.service.getLastCallResponse()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible. However suds supports logging this information via the "suds.metrics" logger (DEBUG log level, see `suds.client.Client:invoke()`).